# How to I pd.merge without creating a copy of the data?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I am trying to join two dataframes together as follows:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', on='key')
```

where df1 and df2 are large datasets with millions of rows. Basically how do I join them without having to create a third dataframe df3.

I just want to join one onto next, changing the original. I don't have enough memory to run so much on my server so I need something more efficient.

Comment: There's a `merge` function on the `DataFrame` object as well, so maybe try `df1.merge(df2)` with the same arguments?

Comment: There is no inplace operation for pandas merging or joining or concatenate functions.

Comment: I need to know two things: 1. are the key values unique; and 2. what are the column names. Tell me this much, and I might be able to help you.

Comment: Short answer: use more RAM. Longer answer: Use something like dask#

Comment: I second dask for this.

Comment: @SpaceImpact as Andrew's answer and this link (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) there is a merge method on the DataFrame object.

What is the implementation? Does it still create a 3rd dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

change how argument to left (left will be the df1 in this example:

`df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')`

Answer (score 0):

I think during merge many duplicate rows were getting created, To fix this u may iterate the dataframe append each iterate data to list. Afterwards u can use pd.concat() with inner merged dataframe.

```
merged_df=[]
split_len=1000
for row_index in range(0,split_len,len(df3)):
   chunk_df=df2[row_index:row_index+split_len]
   merg_df = pd.merge(df1,chunk_df, how='inner', on='key')
   merg_df=merg_df.drop_duplicates()#if u don't want to remove duplicates, command this line.
   merged_df.append(merg_df)
final_df=pd.concat(merged_df)
```

Now u will not face memory issue. You can custom split_len as per your data

Answer (score -3):

You can try this. I am not sure how your data looks like so just guessing.

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_dataset(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='key')
    print(df1)
    return df1

if __name__ == '__main__':

  d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'key': [3, 4]}
  d2 = {'col2': [5,6], 'key': [3, 4]}
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
  # Debug 
  print(df1)
  print(df2)
  merge_dataset(df1, df2)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as posted. Please give it another read.

Comment: @coldspeed hi, I think she wants to merge df1 with df2 by changing df1. I would like to hear your understanding as well

Comment: "Basically how do I join them without having to create a third dataframe df3." `df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='key')` creates "df3" and assigns it to `df1`... does that make sense?

Comment: @coldspeed "creates "df3" and assigns it to df1" answer my question. Thanks for that. So it seems we are not run away from creating a copy?

Comment: Unfortunately, not in this case :-9